# Scaling really large bar compared to other bars in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scaling

I am trying to make a plot in ggplot2 in R with the following code:

```
    feature
[1] abs_deg_sum_1       NumAfterEdits_1     N_1                 NumAfterEdits_3    
[5] TimeSinceLastEdit_2 wt_product_1        NumAfterEdits_2     dwdt_1             
52 Levels: abs_deg_diff_1 abs_deg_diff_2 abs_deg_diff_3 abs_deg_diff_4 ... Z_4



relative_importance
[1] 61.048212 17.235435  1.891542  1.409848  1.356924  1.264824  1.220593  1.184612


library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(feature, relative_importance)
c <- ggplot(df, aes(x = feature, y = relative_importance, fill = feature)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
c + coord_flip()

positions <- c("abs_deg_sum_1", "NumAfterEdits_1", "N_1", "NumAfterEdits_3","TimeSinceLastEdit_2", "wt_product_1", "NumAfterEdits_2",
               "dwdt_1")
c <- c + scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)
c + coord_flip()
```

Since the first value in relative_importance is really large compared to all other values, the plot doesn't show much about the other values. I get the following plot:
[image]

How can I change my code to capture more information in my plot? Especially about the smaller values

Comment: Depends on the message. You could create facets with free y-scales, or add labels to the plot.

Comment: Are you saying that small differences between these low bars are important? Because without more information I find the plot okay as it is (well, I would probably avoid using a bar plot).

Comment: Yeah, I want to depict the difference between small bars more clearly

Comment: I would suggest using a table instead of a bar plot. That way, small differences can be examined, but large differences are not played down.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several options, though I prefer the first or second (or maybe the third if you really want to go with a bar plot):

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(group=LETTERS[1:5], values=c(1.5,0.6,12.6,2.1,85))

# Value labels instead of bars, plus we add a horizontal segment to provide
#  better visual guidance as to the relative values. This also requires
#  some factor gymnastics to be able to get both the segments and the 
#  correct x-axis labels. I've left in the legend, but it's not necessary 
#  and can be removed if you wish.
ggplot(dat, aes(as.numeric(group), values, colour=group)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=as.numeric(group)-0.35, xend=as.numeric(group)+0.35,
                   yend=values), alpha=0.75) +
  geom_text(aes(label=values), fontface="bold", show_guide=FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:5, labels=levels(dat$group))
  #scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,100), breaks=c(0.1, 0.3,1,3,10,30,100)) # For a log scale, if desired
  #coord_flip()  # Flip to horizontal orientation, if desired
```

[image]

```
# Value labels instead of bars
ggplot(dat, aes(group, values, colour=group)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=values), fontface="bold") 

# Bar plot with value labels added
ggplot(dat, aes(group, values, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=values, y=0.5*values), size=5, colour="black") 

# Value labels instead of bars; log scale
ggplot(dat, aes(group, values, colour=group)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=values)) +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,100), breaks=c(0.1,0.3,1,3,10,30,100)) +
  coord_flip()

# Bar plot with log scale. Note that bar baseline is 1 instead of 
#  zero for a log scale, so this doesn't work so well.
ggplot(dat, aes(group, values, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,100), breaks=c(0.1,0.3,1,3,10,30,100)) +
  coord_flip()

# Points instead of bars; log scale
ggplot(dat, aes(group, values, fill=group)) +
  geom_point(pch=21, size=4) +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,100), breaks=c(0.1,0.3,1,3,10,30,100)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the logarithmic axis doesn't work for you and if you have some flexibility in the plot format, you could divide the features into two groups based on the value of relative_importance and show each in it's own panel with appropriate y-scales.  Code including adjustment of bar widths would look like:

```
    library(ggplot2)
# assign rows to Large or Small group
  cut_off_for_small_values <- 3
  small_value_title <- "Expanded_Scale_for_Smaller_Values"
  df  <-  data.frame(feature, relative_importance, 
                     importance_grp = ifelse(relative_importance > cut_off_for_small_values, 
                                             "All", small_value_title))
  # calculate relative bar widths
  width_adj <- .8*nrow(df[df$importance_grp==small_value_title,])/nrow(df)
# plot data
  c <- ggplot(df, aes(x = feature, y = relative_importance, fill = feature))
  c <- c + geom_bar(data=transform(df, importance_grp="All"),
                    stat = "identity")
  c <- c + geom_bar(data=df[df$importance_grp==small_value_title,],
                      stat = "identity", width=width_adj)
   c <- c + geom_text(aes(x = feature, y = relative_importance, 
                          label = format(relative_importance, digits=3), vjust=-.5))
   c <- c + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
  c <- c + facet_wrap(  ~ importance_grp,  scales="free" )
```

which gives plot

[image]